# HTML5 Video Volume

Tags: ios, ipad, html, video

I'm currently working on an HTML5 video player, I have it working fully everywhere, except on the iPad.
Basically, I can control everything, except the sound, I have a `mute` button, it works fine on Google Chrome, Firefox 3.6 and Safari on Mac OS, but on the iPad no matter what value I put in `video.volume`, there is no change happening.

Did anybody get it working properly?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<video src="video_url" width="608" height="476" autobuffer="autobuffer" id="html5-player" preload>
   Your browser doesn't support HTML5.
</video
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
var muted = false;
$j('.player-mute').click(function(){
    if(muted) {
        videoPlayer.volume = 1;
        muted = false;
    } else {
        videoPlayer.volume = 0;
        muted = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of your code (the html and javascript)?  Without any code it's difficult to know what may be wrong.

Comment: The click is properly triggered, the volume value change, but the sound stay the same on the iPad.

Comment: It's a bit of a long shot, but does it make any difference if you specify double (i.e., `videoPlayer.volume = 1.0;` or `videoPlayer.volume = 0.0;`)?

Comment: I've tried both: videoPlayer.volume = 0; videoPlayer.muted = true; and videoPlayer.volume = 0.0; videoPlayer.muted = true; but with no effect. I believe controlling audio with javascript on iPad is broke or deliberately disabled to make you use its hardware controls. See f.e. videojs.com on your iPad, changing the volume has no effect.

Comment: Yeah, i actually discussed with somebody from Apple who told me that it wasn't a bug. They want users to control it with the hardware volume control.

Comment: mark something as an answer please.

Comment: Ah apple... Thanks to you it feels like the good old times again: lets' write we support the standard on the package, but let's implement something else.

Answer (score 31):

The `volume` property on the iOS devices is **read-only** according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html):

> On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.

Comment: Direct HTML link to the iOS page: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Comment: it's crazy at apple, if I'm in a conference and I have two videos and I just want to lower the volume of a person how to do?

Answer (score 4):

If you read the iPad html5 video documentation it says that only the user of the device can start video, and change volume.

Comment: If it's triggered by a click event it should work, no? I mean it work for the video play(), i have a click event binded on my play button and i have no issue, whereas the mute button doesn't work, may be because it's a property that i modify?

Answer (score 1):

As @dobrin said, the `volume` property is read only on IOS for the video.

However, you could use the `muted` property, this allow you to mute or unmute video, most of the time, this will respond to the problem.

So, you can't set a specific volume between 0 and 1 but you can set the volume either to 0 or 1, then Apple assume that you will use the physical buttons for setting the volume.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/muted

Answer (score -7):

```
var muted = false;
$j('.player-mute').click(function(){
if(muted) {
    videoPlayer.volume(1);
    muted = false;
} else {
    videoPlayer.volume(0);
    muted = true;
}
});
```

use like function

Comment: volume attribute of video element is not a function.