# Mute sound from youtube in iOS uiwebview

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uiwebview, youtube-javascript-api

I'm building an app that relies on playing videos from youtube in a uiwebview.  This is all going fine, but sometimes I need the videos to be silent even if the user has their volume turned up.  The youtube javascript api has an option for this, but apparently it is ignore in iOS according to what I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/youtube-api-gdata/mute$20not$20working$20ios/youtube-api-gdata/We4cDlE6kRQ/iycM6fPh2i4J).

And covered in this stackoverflow question here:
[HTML5 Video Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602541/html5-video-volume)

I then tried to use the volume property and the setvolume method on MPMusicPlayerController to mute the app volume instead.  I realize these have been deprecated since iOS 7.0, but they do still work at least for now.  However the app is being written in swift and that property and method aren't even accessible anymore.

Is there any way left for me to be able to mute a youtube video playing inside a uiwebivew?