# Any New Workarounds for A-Frame Videos on iOS not Playing?

Tags: ios, video, safari, aframe, ar.js

I've been learning how to use AR.js and A-Frame to display videos in an AR space, but I've come across the fabled issue with playing videos on an iOS devices.

When researching this issue, I found several threads that presented workarounds. The most common trends were to include `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` , put `playinline` and/or `webkit-playinline` in`<video>`, and have an interaction from the user to play the video (such as a button press, a screen tap, or et cetera). I also found a library that supposedly handles these issues called [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/fregante/iphone-inline-video).

My References:

- https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-video-not-play
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari
- https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1846
- https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/316#issuecomment-183006679
- https://github.com/misterburton/ideo-sf-vr-nerd-night#bonus-points
- [Can't play video texture under a-frame framework on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555905/cant-play-video-texture-under-a-frame-framework-on-iphone)
- [Why is my video or videosphere not playing on mobile in A-Frame VR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380912/why-is-my-video-or-videosphere-not-playing-on-mobile-in-a-frame-vr)

However, none of their solutions worked with my code. Looking through my research, a lot of the posts were rather dated, so I wanted to know if there has been any new knowledge at tackling this issue? If not, does anyone know why the commonly suggested workarounds don't work in my example (am I using them incorrectly)?

EDIT:
Also, I'm testing this on an iPhone 6s with **iOS 13.4.1**

My code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/iphone-inline-video.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
    
    <script>
      //Loads Videos
      AFRAME.registerComponent("vidloader", {
        init: function () {
          this.materialLoaded = this.materialLoaded.bind(this);
          console.log("init");
          // wait until the material is ready
          this.el.addEventListener("loaded", this.materialLoaded);
        },
        materialLoaded: function () {
          // grab the material
          let material = this.el.getObject3D("mesh").material;
          console.log(material.map.format);
          // swap the format
          material.map.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
          material.map.needsUpdate = true;
          console.log(material.map);
        },
        remove: function () {
          this.el.removeEventListener("loaded", this.materialLoaded);
        },
      });
      // Handles Playing/Pausing (User must tap the screen once for the video[s] to play)
      // Set up for multiple markers+videos later...
      AFRAME.registerComponent('vidhandler', {
        schema: {
          videos: { type: 'string' }
        },
        init: function () {
          this.clickCheck = false
          this.videoNodes = document.querySelectorAll(this.data.videos)
          document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
            this.clickCheck = true
          });
        },
        //Handles playing marker-specifc videos
        tick: function () {
          if (this.el.object3D.visible == true) {
            if (!this.toggle && Boolean(this.clickCheck)) {
              this.toggle = true;
              for (let i = 0; i < this.videoNodes.length; i++) {
                this.videoNodes[i].play();
              }
            }
          } else {
            if (this.toggle) {
              for (let i = 0; i < this.videoNodes.length; i++) {
                this.videoNodes[i].pause();
              }
              this.toggle = false;
              this.clickCheck = false
            }
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
      embedded 
    arjs>
      <a-assets>
        <video
          id="bunny-vid"
          loop="true"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.com/f8908c29-7a4c-455b-93ca-6172548f04c2%2FBig_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_1080p.ogv.360p.vp9.webm?v=1566582340300"
          playsinline 
          webkit-playsinline
        ></video>
      </a-assets>
      <a-marker preset='hiro' vidhandler='videos: #bunny-vid'>
        <a-video
        vidloader
        width="1.32"
        height="1"
        rotation="270 0 0"
        position="0 0.10 0"
        src="#bunny-vid"
        material="transparent: true"
        ></a-video>
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haven't had time to read through all of the posts you linked, so you may have already tried this... but I recently solved a similar problem by muting the video.

("muted" attribute on the <a-video>)

Comment: @DiarmidMackenzie I tried that as well, both in `<a-video>` and in `<video>`, but the video still doesn't play. :(