# Sound button doesn't exist on safari

Tags: javascript, plyr.js

I have a web site developed with video player made with plyr and everything works fine for every browser except safari from IOS because it does not show volume button.
the following Html code is for player:

```
<video muted class="videoplayer onPouse" poster="{{@$item->postThumbnail->url}}" playsinline >
               <source src="{{asset($item->video)}}" type="video/mp4">
           </video>
```

And here is my script:

```
player = Plyr.setup(currentPlayer, {
               controls: ['play-large', 'play', 'mute', 'progress', 'volume'],
               volume: 1,
               fullscreen: {
                   enabled: false
               }
           });
```

The weird thing is that this volume button does not exist on their official (plyr).
Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Video Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602541/html5-video-volume)

Comment: problem is that I can't see this button for volume to click on it. In that article is said that 'I have a mute button' but I don't have